# media query not working as expected when using orientation

Tags: css

I have written an internal css to change background color of the body.From screen 601px to 700px i want the background to be lightblue and in landscape i want the background to be red.My problem is that i only get the background as red only can anyone help me with this.

```
<style>
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:601px) and (max-width:700px){
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 734px) and (orientation: landscape){
body {
    background-color: red;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: what if you add min-width and max-width

Comment: in screens between 601 and 700 background color will be red not blue.I only want red background in landscape mode

Comment: in landscape its red and when its not in landscape it blue? if its like that its working when it reach the height of landscape its red

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 734px) and (orientation: landscape){
body {    background-color: red; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.Suppose that the device width is 600*700 in that i want the bgcolor to be blue and in its landscape ie 700*600 i want bg to be red